# How can I stop a while loop before it completes the loop

Tags: python

i'm very new to python.

I'm having a problem with one class and another. My while loop will let the enemy attack squirtle, or squirtle attack the enemy, depending on who got the first move.

```
while dead<1:
    squirtle.attacked()
    squirtle.healthcheck()
    enemy1.attacked()
    enemy1.healthcheck()
```

In each of the healthcheck functions it asks if the enemy or squirtle is equal to or less than 0, if it is then dead=1 and the loop should stop. However if squirtle dies then the rest of that block still runs; the enemy is attacked by a dead squirtle.

I was wondering if there was a way to exit the block midway through

Comment: use `break`  with a condition

Comment: Read the basics before blindly asking it here

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the `break` statement [reference](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)

A sample code -

```
while True:
    x = input('Input a number :')
    if x == "1":
        break;
```

The above code would break when you input the number `1` .

You will have to adapt your program to use this `break` statement

Answer (score 0):

## use [`break`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm)

the following is an addition to your snippet based on the description you provided

```
while dead<1:
    squirtle.attacked()
    if enemy1.healthcheck() <= 0:
        break

    enemy1.attacked()
    if enemy1.healthcheck() <= 0:
        break
```